Repetir Valores en celda NA hasta llegar a una con valor
Necesito ayuda para completar valores en la columna "Asig.", necesito rellenar por ejemplo el valor 201 en las NA hasta llegar a la celda con el valor 001, y luego que se rellene con 001 hasta que llegue a la próxima con valor, en este caso 999 y así sucesivamente.
Gracias por la orientación


Me parece que en este caso un enfoque iterativo estándar es lo más apropiado:
replace_values <- function(x) {
  new <- x
  last <- NA
  for (i in seq_along(x)) {
    if (!is.na(x[i])) {
      last <- x[i]
    }
    new[i] <- last
  }
  new
}

La lógica es sencilla, mantengo el último valor no NA y actualizo los datos hasta que encuentro otro valor no NA.
data$n_sig <- replace_values(data$asig)

data
    
  asig n_asig
1 <NA>   <NA>
2 <NA>   <NA>
3 <NA>   <NA>
4  201    201
5 <NA>    201
6 <NA>    201
7  001    001
8 <NA>    001
9  999    999


Gracias por la ayuda y el tiempo!!

Lo que estás buscando es un algoritmo de imputación de datos perdidos. Si bien existen muchos, tú en particular buscar un algoritmo llamado last observation carried forward o arrastre de la última observación. Si quieres rellenar los primeros registros, usarías last observation carried backwards. En este caso, no es precisamente imputación de datos, sino que relleno en base a un criterio personal. La imputación requiere el cumplimiento de ciertos supuestos.
Volviendo al problema, te recomiendo la librería {zoo}, que si bien está pensada en datos temporales, incorpora una serie de funciones prácticas para imputar datos:
Asig <- c(NA,NA,NA,'201',NA,NA,'001',NA,'999',NA)

zoo::na.locf(Asig, na.rm = FALSE)
#  [1] NA    NA    NA    "201" "201" "201" "001" "001" "999" "999"


Gracias por la ayuda!

Sin duda esta es la forma en cómo lo hubiera resuelto en primera instancia. +1!

Siguiendo la lógica y aplica misma explicación de @aldo_tapia, también existe una alternativa en el paquete tidyr: la función fill
> Asig <- c(NA,NA,NA,'201',NA,NA,'001',NA,'999',NA)
> library(tidyr)
> fill(data.frame(Asig), Asig)
   Asig
1  <NA>
2  <NA>
3  <NA>
4   201
5   201
6   201
7   001
8   001
9   999
10  999

Aquí te dejo otras opciones.
